# I do not understand this error involving two objects with a many-to-many relation with one another

Tags: django

I am implementing a web interface for email lists.  When a list administrator logs in, the site will visually display which lists they are an owner of and corresponding information about the lists.  For this I have decided to have two tables:

1)  An owner table which contains entries for information about list administrators.  Each of these entries contains a 'ManyToManyField' which holds the information about which lists the owner in any given entry is an administrator for.

2)  A list table which contains entries with information about each email list.  Each entry contains the name of the list a 'ManyToManyField' holding information about which owners are administrators the list.

Here is the code in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class ListEntry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    owners = models.ManyToManyField('OwnerEntry')
    date = models.DateTimeField('date created')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class OwnerEntry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    lists = models.ManyToManyField('ListEntry')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

I have already set up a simple local database to create a basic working website with.  I have populated it with test entries using this code:

```
from list_app.models import *
from datetime import *

le1 = ListEntry(
    name = "Physics 211 email list",
    date = datetime.now(),
)
le1.save()

le2 = ListEntry(
    name = "Physics 265 email list",
    date = datetime(2014,1,1),
)
le2.save()

oe1 = OwnerEntry(
    name = 'wasingej',
)
oe1.save()
oe1.lists.add(le1,le2)
le1.owners.add(oe1)
le2.owners.add(oe1)

oe2 = OwnerEntry(
    name = 'doej',
)
oe2.save()
oe2.lists.add(le1)
le1.owners.add(oe2)
```

Here is where my error occurs:  When the user has logged in via CAS, I have them redirected to this page in views.py:

```
def login_success(request):
    u = OwnerEntry(name=request.user)
    print(u.name)
    print(u.lists)
    return HttpResponse("login success!")
```

At the line 'print(u.lists)', I get the error **"" needs to have a value for field "ownerentry" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your model structure is broken, for a start. You don't need ManyToManyFields on *both* sides of the relationship, only one - Django will provide the accessor for the reverse relationship.

Your issue is happening because you are not querying an existing instance from the database, you are instantiating an unsaved one. To query, you use `model.objects.get()`:

```
u = OwnerEntry.objects.get(name=request.user.username)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide the actual class to the ManyToManyField constructor, not a string.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/